# How to update div with jQuery from within div after it has loaded?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am using jQuery to load a new page inside the div "example-placeholder"

```
<script>
function example_ajax_request() {
  var parameters = "ajax.html?";
  $('example-placeholder').load(parameters);
}
<script>

<div id="example-placeholder">
<p>Start typing text here and it will be replaced by the results list</p>
</div>
```

This loads the file **ajax.html** into the div as expected (I've left off the parameters after the '?' for clarity but they work fine)

What I want to do is reload ajax.html into the same div using a link generated *within* ajax.html, but with different parameters.

For example, I have a list of results generated by ajax.html which display a bunch of paging links.  I want to load, say, **ajax.html?page=2** into the div "example-placeholder" without reloading the whole page again.

Comment: "ajax.html" is a php or aspx file?

Comment: You have $('example-placeholder'.load(parameters); I think you left off a close parenthesis after placeholder in your example. 

$('example-placeholder').load(parameters);

Comment: it's actually a newlisp file but it should operate identically to what a PHP file would do.

Comment: whoops fixed the closed parenthesis, that was a typo, the code had them originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#example-placeholder a').live('click', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); 
   $('#example-placeholder').load($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

This script should bind the function to all links within `example-placeholder` after they have been created as the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/) promises to bind the event handler to all matching elements now and in the future.

The [preventDefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) prevents the links from changing the `window.location`.

And the last line tries to update the `example-placeholder` with the contents of the page found using the link url.

Answer (score 0):

inside your `ajax.html` page whenever you are ready to reload it do :

```
window.location = newUrl;
```

where `newUrl` could be a string like `'/ajax.html?page=2&x=y'`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script>
function example_ajax_request(event) {

  var 
     parameters = "ajax.html?";

  if (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    parameters = $(this).attr('href');
  }

  $('example-placeholder').load(parameters);

  return false;
}

$("example-placeholder").delegate("a", "click", example_ajax_request)

<script>

<div id="example-placeholder">
<p>Start typing text here and it will be replaced by the results list</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the callback function to manipulate the html that gets inserted into the `#example-placeholder` element:

```
<script>
function example_ajax_request() {
  var parameters = "ajax.html?";
  $('example-placeholder').load(parameters, function(){
    // manipulate data
  });
}
<script>
```